# Filter tweets in python depending on possibly_sensitive value

Tags: python, twitter, streaming

I use a twitter bot and try hard to filter out tweets from my retweets that share inappropriate content. 
Thus I want to filter all tweets out of my retweets that have "possibly_sensitive:true".
The bot is in python and I use the stream api method, have already imported tweepy and twystream.
the first approach i tried was to

```
elif jsonData['possibly_sensitive']
```

within a several steps query to filter out things i dont want to retweet. It wont even work a single time, basically the output hasnt changed at all.

the second approach was to enhance the track command for the `stream.filter` alike

```
keyword = "#hashtag filter:possibly_sensitive"
```

or tried this too:

```
keyword = "#hashtag possibly_sensitive:false"
```

as nothing works and I cannot really find other answers that helped me so far I am this desperated and joined stackoverflow.

Pls help me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the search API, try `-filter:safe`

Comment: I think this doesnt really work. Is this filter removing all tweets from the feed, with a picture as well? I tried it for 24hrs now and the changed query wont show up anything, probably as a later query singles tweets without a picture out.
I think the safe filter will look for a media or link in general and mark all these as unsafe. The possibly_sensitive destinguishes between those marked as adult content and those that are open freely, this would also suit my query case. But thank you so much for you answer. I hadnt tried this.